# Prove that if function $g$ is the inverse of function $f,$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ implies $f(x)=x$

Tags: functions

> Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$ the inverse function of $f$, where $A$ and $B$ are included in $R+$, and $f$ and $g$ are different functions.
>
> Prove that if $f(x)=g(x)$ for a number $x$, then $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

My idea was to prove firstly that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ are symmetric with respect to the line $x=y$ (How do I prove it?). Then, let $y=f(x) $ and I wanted to suppose by contradiction that, for example, $x<y$. Then the point $(x,y)$ is on both the graph of $f$ and the graph of $g,$ but it is only on one side of the line $x=y$.

Can you please give me a detailed, step by step, proof of the initial statement? Thank you!

Comment: Title: $f(x)=-x$ also has $g(x)=-x$, but not $f(x)=g(x)=x$?

Comment: I corrected the title. Thank you

Comment: is it for a number $x$ or for all numbers?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are different functions, how can you prove that $f(x)=g(x)=x?$

Comment: as @AdrianKeister asked... did you mean Differentiable functions in their domain??

Comment: I meant that f(x)=g(x)=x holds ONLY for that specific x which is the solution of f(x)=g(x).

Answer (score 2):

The claim is not true:

Let $A=B=[0,1]$ and $$f(x):=(1-x)^2\quad(0\leq x\leq1),\qquad g(y):=1-\sqrt{y}\quad(0\leq y\leq 1)\ .$$
Then $f(0)=g(0)=1\ne0$.